# how to trigger a css animation after certain pixels of scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, scroll

I have a page with a section where there are three images that animate in from left to right with a slight overlap between their timelines.

I am trying to make the animations start after 200px vertical scrolling.

What is the best way to achieve this? CSS only or do I need to use javascript?

Comment: you'll need js. css can do SOME basic animals based on some events, like `:hover`, but it CAN'T check how far you've scrolled and trigger something based on that.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of any jquery or open-source js I can use?

Comment: it'd probably take 3-4 lines of jquery to attach to the scroll even and compare things. you don't need anything other than core jquery for that.

Comment: I'm not very familiar much with javascript. I'll look around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this with jQuery..

```
   /// you probably want to set this dynamically
   var change1 = 200;
    $(document).scroll(function() {

        // you might need to throttle the listener
        if (Math.random() < 0.15) {

            if( $(this).scrollTop() > change1) { 
                updateCSS(var);
   }}})


function updateCSS(var) {
    $image1.css({attribute: x);
    $image2.css({attribute: y);
    $image3.css({attribute: z);
}
```

Comment: Definitely. You posed a general problem and this is a general solution. You will need to add the image id's in the $image slots and insert the css attributes you want to change. Without knowing more about your specific problem, this is only a general framework for getting you on the way to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might check this pout too:

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

skrollr can do a lot more than just what you have in mind, but its pretty easy to handle and can take care of your design and much more.